# Avoid national borders in HERE maps

Tags: javascript, here-api

Is it possible to request route which will be located only in one country without crossing national borders of other countries?(I'm using JS)

Comment: Have you looked into something like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-multiple-countries it might be what you are looking for with a quick google?

Comment: @StephenMiller He didn't say he's using Google maps, it's tagged as "here-api" so he must be using here maps.

Comment: @Adriani6 Thanks, is didn’t see that at all.

Comment: @stephenmiller  most likely there will be much more HERE maps Qs here, because they announced a new free plan which gives you 250K free requests per month which is more than Google gives you and they don't require a credit card either, so I expect quite a few google maps devs switching to here maps in the coming months and coming here with questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, our API does not have option to restrict routing to certain country.

A workaround would be to list all neighboring countries in `&excludeCountries` parameter:

```
excludeCountries - Countries that must be excluded from route calculation. 
                   Type: list of common:CountryCodeType.
                   example: excludecountries='AUT,CHE'
```

Comment: Any plans on implementing this feature without the workaround in the foreseeable future?